# About the closed form for $\lim_{y\to +\infty}\left(-\frac{2}{\pi}\log(1+y)+\int_{0}^{y}\frac{|\cos x\,|}{1+x}\,dx\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, special-functions, fourier-series, closed-form

Recently, when facing [a baby Rudin's exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231772/showing-that-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x-dx-diverges-baby-rudin-exe/1231813#1231813), I proved that:
$$ \int_{0}^{y}\frac{|\cos x\,|}{1+x}\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\log(1+y)+O(1) $$
holds by integration by parts.

> Now I wonder if $$\color{red}{L}=\lim_{y\to
>  +\infty}\left(-\frac{2}{\pi}\log(1+y)+\int_{0}^{y}\frac{|\cos x\,|}{1+x}\,dx\right)$$ has a nice closed form expression.

It is easy to argue that, since the Fourier series of $|\cos x\,|$ is given by:
$$ |\cos x\,|=\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n^2-1}\cos(2nx)\tag{A} $$
our constant is given by:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x)\cos(2x)\,dx,\tag{B} $$
where:
$$ f(x) = \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(4n^2-1)(x+n)},\tag{C} $$
hence $L$ is probably related with the [Clausen function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function). Numerically, 
$$ L \approx 0.057813. \tag{D}$$
By using the identity stated in the comments and Fubini's theorem we also have:
$$ L = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{y}{1+y^2}\left(-1+2\arctan(e^{-y})\cosh(y)\right)\,dy.\tag{E}$$

Comment: Probably $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4n^2-1}e^{ny}=-\frac{1}{2}+\arctan(e^{y/2})\cosh(y/2)$$ is pretty useful.

Comment: Have you tried writing the integral as a sum $\int_0^{\pi /2}\frac{|\cos x|}{1+x}dx+ \sum_{n=0}^N \int_{(n+1/2)\pi}^{(n+3/2)\pi} \frac{|\cos x|}{1+x}dx$ and performing multiple integration by parts?

Comment: @Dr.MV: is that really different from just using the Fourier series of $|\cos x\,|$?

Comment: That is a good question.  I have not "turned the crank" to determine if that is so.